# Add a new line to a table and auto populating certain fields with specific text

Tags: excel, vba

Have VBA knowledge but cannot make the below formula worl.
Problem: create a new line and add an "S" into the column C but new row line.
Insert into column E (new row line) the name of the active sheet created.

Continuously create new lines in succession throughout the year.

```
NewName = InputBox("Debit note Number")
Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Supplier]]").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
ActiveCell.Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Rows("1:1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
OneMore = False
```

Answer (score 0):

See documentation for [ListObjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobjects)

```
Option Explicit
Sub insertRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    Dim oTbl As ListObject, oListRow As ListRow
    Set oTbl = ws.ListObjects.Item("Table1")
    Set oListRow = oTbl.ListRows.Add
    oListRow.Range.Value = oListRow.Range.Offset(-1, 0).Value
    oListRow.Range.Cells(1, 3).value = "S"
    oListRow.Range.Cells(1, 5).value = "New Sheet"

End Sub
```